# Laravel Validator fails due to array to string conversion

Tags: php, validation, laravel-4

I'm trying to validate this input:

```
$values = [                                                
    'id'                => $input['id'][$i],   
    'template_id'       => $input['template_id'][$i],   
    'schedulable_id'    => $id,                               
    'schedulable_type'  => $type,       
    'order_by'          => $i                                 
];
```

Against these rules found in my Schedule class:

```
public static $rules = [                                                                                         
    'template_id'           => 'required|integer|exists:templates,id',                                        
    'schedulable_id'        => 'required|integer',                                                                  
    'schedulable_type'      => 'required|in:Item,Order',
    'order_by'              => 'integer'                                                                            
];
```

When I do the following, I always get an array to string conversion error in "/laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Validation/Validator.php" on line 905:

```
$validator = Validator::make($values, Schedule::$rules);

if ($validator->fails()) {
    $errors[$i] = $validator->messages();

    continue;
}
```

Why would this be happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just discovered I had Ardent's `$forceEntityHydrationFromInput = true` and my input cannot be pulled directly from `Input` for validation purposes due to the fact that it is submitted as an array of partially referenced values.

To fix this, change to `$forceEntityHydrationFromInput = false` and use standard input validation procedure instead of relying on Ardent's magic.

Sometimes clever packages are too clever.

Comment: @grald it's set in the attributes of your model. If you didn't set it in the first place, this likely isn't your problem.

Comment: i don't know it yet because i never set actually i am using L5.1