# Validation Error (Array to string conversion) in laravel 5.1

Tags: laravel-5, laravel-5.1

I'm struggling a couple of hours to fix this error but no luck please I need help about this error always says: 
(Array to string conversion)

**Code:**

```
<?php 
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Validator;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Requests;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Bus\DispatchesJobs;
use Illuminate\Routing\Controller as BaseController;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Validation\ValidatesRequests;
use Hash, Auth, URL, Route, Cart, View, Paypal;
use App\Product, App\ProductBenefit, App\Country, App\Currency, App\User, App\City;

class HomeController extends BaseController {
public function postCheckoutStepPayment(Request $request){
        if(!is_null($request->input('ship_to_diff_address'))){
            $validate = Validator::make($request->all(), User::$rules);
            if($validate->fails()) { //<- problem this part
               return 'failed';
            }

        }
   }
}
```

> User.php

```
public static $rules = array(
             'diff_firstname' => 'required',
             'diff_lastname'  => 'required',
             'diff_phone'     => 'required',
             'diff_countries' => 'required',
             'diff_city'      => 'required',
             'diff_state'     => 'required',
             'diff_address'   => 'required',
             );
```

[image]

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Comment: @MinaAbadir Array to string conversion error

Comment: Possible duplicates: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25691523/laravel-validator-fails-due-to-array-to-string-conversion

Comment: @MinaAbadir that answer is not clear to me

Comment: I am saying it's a possible duplicates. Are you using any classes that might change the default behavior of passing requests input?

Comment: Nope i'm just using the default

Comment: Try `$request->input()` instead of `$request->all()`. Might work for you.

Comment: @TimLewis i am already try that but no luck

Comment: can you share the full error stack ?

Comment: @Vikas Please check i added an image

Comment: What's the value of locale in your config/app.php ?

Comment: the default value and with the class of PayPal

Answer (score 1):

It appears that the value for locale in your config/app.php is an array, whereas the function loadPath in vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Translation/FileLoader.php expects it to be a string.
So I suggest you to set it's value to either 'en' or 'sv' in the config file and then later change it programmatically in your code as required.

Comment: Your the best @Vikas you save my day thank you very much :)

Answer (score 0):

Add this class in you controller

```
use App\Http\Requests;
```

And Try this code in blade file.

```
 @if(isset($errors))
     <ul style="list-style: none;" class="alert alert-warning">
     @foreach($errors->all() as $content)
         <li>{{$content}}</li>
     @endforeach
     </ul>
 @endif
```

Comment: My controller can't proceed to the view because of the error in validation part in my controller

Comment: check request have variable. first line  befor $v .print_r($request->all());

Comment: take a quick look i am updating my post

Answer (score 0):

add `use Redirect` at the top, and

```
 public function postRegister(Request $request)
        {
            $v = Validator::make($request->all(), [
             'firstname' => 'required',
             'lastname'  => 'required',
             'phone'     => 'required',
             'countries' => 'required',
             'city'      => 'required',
             'state'     => 'required',
             'address'   => 'required',
            ]);

            if ($v->fails()) { 
                return redirect::to('register')
                            ->withErrors($v->messages())
                            ->withInput();
            }


        }
```

Comment: You don't need `use Redirect` when using `redirect()`, only when using `Redirect::to()`, and what did you change about `postRegister()`, the variable name?

Comment: instead of `$validator`,  `$validator->messages()`

Comment: @Sid actually there's no problem with that part my problem is the if statement   if ($v->fails()) this part something went wrong

Comment: @Sid take a quick look i am updating my post